# How to measure containers execution time inside a kubernetes POD?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I am running a jobs with a  kubernetes POD  and I need to measure the execution time for each job .

I want to get it  through some api.

Does anyone know how can I get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A job has a property denominated `status` of type [JobStatus](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#jobstatus-v1-batch).

The properties which you are looking for in the `JobStatus` type is the `startTime` and the `completionTime`, which as the name suggest are responsible for indicating the moment where the job started/completed. The difference between these values is going to lead you to the duration of the execution of the job.